# Remove all bunch of 0 from Ac**000**vd0 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Remove all bunch of 0 from Ac**000**vd0 in SQL Server... Single 0 should remain same

Comment: unclear what you're asking. Please edit your question.

Comment: Is there a known maximum number of consecutive zeroes? Is it possible to have multiple groups of zeroes?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove those 3 zeroes, try this:

```
SELECT Replace (YourFieldName,'000','') AS YourFieldName
FROM YourTableName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested `REPLACE`, following removes up to 38 consecutive zeroes:

```
replace(replace(replace(replace(x,'00000','0'), '0000', '0'), '000', '0'), '00','0')
```